# Cannot convert parameter from T to T&

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with calling calling specialized template function.

My code goes like this:

```
namespace{
    struct Y {};
}

template<>
bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud<Y>(const typename pcl::PointCloud< Y >::ConstPtr &cloud, const std::string &id, int viewport);
```

and the calling spot is:

```
pcl::PointCloud<Y>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<Y>);
visualizer->addPointCloud(cloud, "cloud", 0);
```

Error I am getting is

```
'bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(const boost::shared_ptr<T> &,const std::string &,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<T> &'
```

Here are some declarations and typedefs from library:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointT> > Ptr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<PointT> > ConstPtr;

template <typename PointT> bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(
    const typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr &cloud,
    const std::string &id, int viewport
)
```

I've tried with the `boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<Y> > cloud;`, but same error rises again.

I am desperately trying to debug one issue in the library which would be very easy to debug if I could access one private map, and iterate through it, but I can't compile the whole library as it would take some time (and I just want to peek into it - I know it is wrong, but I am struggling for the whole day with this)

Compiler is VC++ 10.

Thank you

Comment: Are there more lines to the error message?

Comment: No, there are not - only this message. Also, function code is trivial (`return true;` for the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thank you all for answering me on this question. Ben Voigt helped with directing me to look into template parameters, not on actual type conversion error message, and Yakk for writing his code down.

In the meantime, I tried to break my code into a simple functions, and that generated different error for me this time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


template<typename PointT>
class PointCloud
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointT> > Ptr;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<PointT> > ConstPtr;

};


class PCLVisualizer
{
    public:
        template<typename PointT>
        bool addPointCloud(
            const typename PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr &cloud,
            const std::string &id, int viewport
        ){}
};

namespace{
    struct Y {};
}

template<>
bool PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud<Y>(const typename PointCloud< Y >::ConstPtr &cloud, const std::string &id, int viewport)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    PCLVisualizer p;
    PointCloud<Y>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<Y>());
    p.addPointCloud(cloud, "cloud", 0); 
}
```

Error now was:

```
error C2783: 'bool PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud(const PointCloud<PointT>::ConstPtr &,const std::string &,int)' : could not deduce template argument for 'PointT'
```

So, I now saw what I needed to do in the first place (and I am going out to shoot myself, as I am not feeling very smart right now :) ):

```
getVisualizer()->addPointCloud<Y>(cloud, "cloud", 0);
```

Again, thank you all!

Comment: Burgos, mark your own answer as having solved your problem (if your problem is solved!) -- select the check mark next to your answer and make it bright green.

Answer (score 2):

Evidently `T` is not the same both times it appears inside the error message.

Specifically, since your header uses `ConstPtr` and your caller code uses `Ptr`, I suspect that one is `shared_ptr<Object>` and the other is `shared_ptr<const Object>`.  The error results then, because these types are not related.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In `PointCloud`, I have  'typedef boost::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<PointT> > ConstPtr;', so I've changed `cloud` to `boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<Y> > cloud;`, but same error appears. Let me update question with the original signature of `addPointCloud` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

namespace{
    struct Y {};
}

template<typename T>
struct PointCloud {
  typedef std::shared_ptr<PointCloud<T>> Ptr;
  typedef std::shared_ptr<const PointCloud<T>> ConstPtr;
};

template<typename T>
void addPointCloud(typename PointCloud<T>::ConstPtr const &cloud) {}

int main() {
  PointCloud<Y>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<Y>());
  addPointCloud<Y>( cloud );
}
```

The above code runs fine.  Thus whatever your problem is, it isn't in the code you are showing us.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not trying people to read my mind - this error doesn't have anything with the error that I am trying to resole - I am just trying to resolve this problem, and for other problem, I've already asked on pcl-users, but nobody is answering, so I am trying to "build" something on my own :). I am trying to break the code down to include only what is wrong. I can't see my major problem in your code - template specialization for Y - and that is causing my problem - library code is working just fine.